# How to find root cause for "The Report.enabled property has been deprecated." warning

Tags: android, gradle, gradle-plugin

I see a warning in my code about a deprecated property `Report.enabled`

```
The Report.enabled property has been deprecated. This is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 8.0. 
Please use the required property instead. 
See https://docs.gradle.org/7.4.2/dsl/org.gradle.api.reporting.Report.html#org.gradle.api.reporting.Report:enabled for more details.
```

That I don't directly use. Is there a way to find out from which dependency is it coming from without the "raw" solution of removing dependencies until the warning is gone?

Answer (score 2):

It can be done by using `--warning-mode fail --stacktrace` with the Gradle command, for instance

```
./gradlew build --warning-mode fail --stacktrace
```